# Commas appearing in html after array mapping

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have made a map of an array that take the value of it to show a corresponding image.
Everything works fine except for the fact some commas are appearing between those lines.

[image: Example]

I have tried to convert the array to string and remove the commas, but then the mapping stops working for a reason I can't truly understand.

Right now mapping goes like:

```
  const images = imgArr.map(n => `<p><img src="img/test/${n}.png" style="width: 100px; min-width: 500px; image-rendering: crisp-edges;" /> </p>`)
  var h = document.getElementById("myH2");
  h.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", images);
```

Any idea how can I proceed with this?

Comment: Join the array using `Array.prototype.join('')` to append without the commas

Comment: This breaks it for some reason... it works when I show it as a string but now when I map it

Comment: What exactly did you do?

Comment: I got an array from a solidity file which comes in uint256 and I mapped it.
When I convert it to strings with toString() it stops working, and any sort of change I try to do to it such a .join breaks it too.

Comment: Check out my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`.join('')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method on array, to convert to a string without the commas

```
...  
h.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", images.join(''));
```